# Android emulator -- DDMS "emulator control" is disabled while running buildroid/virtualbox based emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, location, virtualbox, ddms

I'm running an android emulator with virtualbox / buildroid, and connecting with ADB and eclipse, DDMS,

Everything is working, I'm able to load apps from eclipse etc, BUT the emulator controls in DDMS perspective are greyed out, so I'm unable to send location data to the device.

Is it impossible to send location data from DDMS to a virtualbox based emulator, or is this a configuration issue?

Also is there an alternative way to send mock GPS data to my emulator (I tried to use a 'mock location' application , but it keeps asking for a location source to be enabled, even though I've enabled wifi/gps (I know that emulators aren't able to use actual GPS etc, so can this be faked?)

Comment: Yes it is possible to send mock location using DDBMS control

Comment: ok thanks, well if possible using DDMS (DDBMS?) than why is my emulator control greyed out in Eclipse?

Comment: make sure your device is selected in DDBMS

Comment: thx, Dinesh well my device is selected in DDMS but emulator control is still greyed out

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a new way to send GPS data to an emulator .. the new emulator got a side bar with icons .. use the three dot sign (the hamburger icon) .. now u will open a window where u can send GPS to your device